# Too many levels of symbolic links - moving a Windows installation

Tags: windows, nautilus, ntfs, symbolic-link, copy-and-paste

I have an NTFS drive containing a bootable Windows 10 drive C installation. In Ubuntu 22.04, I am using Files (is it still Nautilus?) to move that installation to another NTFS drive. Within that installation, the top-level ProgramData folder contains an Application Data subfolder. The icon displayed for that subfolder contains a diagonal arrow. According to [LinuxLinks](https://www.linuxlinks.com/linux-starters-guide-linux-understanding-file-system/), this icon signifies a soft link:

[image]

When I try to move the ProgramData folder to the target drive, Nautilus says that it is "Preparing to move." Its calculations indicate that it has found 273GB. That seems erroneous. The entire drive C installation is only about 30GB.

The problem seems to arise from an infinite self-referential loop in the Application Data subfolder. Specifically, the move effort terminates with an error:

> Error opening directory '/media/ray/PROGRAMS/ProgramData/Application
> Data/Application Data/ [...] /Application Data/Documents/My Music':
> Too many levels of symbolic links

An answer to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233534/how-do-i-deal-with-too-many-levels-of-symbolic-links) suggests using `rsync` instead of `cp`. Presumably that means Nautilus can't handle the move. I'm not sure which `rsync` options, if any, will move the source folder in a way that results in an exact replica on the target drive, or whether there may be a better solution for this particular case.

Comment: You can try `sudo rsync -aXS --progress --rsync-path="nice rsync" /[origin] /[destination] --dry-run` If it looks good, do it again and omit the `--dry-run` caveat: This is my standard rsync syntax, but I have no experience using it on NTFS